# Why does order matter in Rails routes.rb when using resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I receive an error when my route is listed as such:

```
resources :coupons
get 'coupons/redeem_coupon', to: 'coupons#redeem_coupon', as: 'redeem_coupon'
```

The error is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Coupon with 'id'=redeem_coupon:
```

When I reverse the order to:

```
get 'coupons/redeem_coupon', to: 'coupons#redeem_coupon', as: 'redeem_coupon'
resources :coupons
```

It works fine.  I understand that resources creates these routes

```
GET /coupons
GET /coupons/new    
POST    /coupons    
GET /coupons/:id    
GET /coupons/:id/edit   
PATCH/PUT   /coupons/:id        
DELETE  /coupons/:id
```

Is listing my custom route first, more specific or overriding the other route?  Why does the order matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is because rails tries to match routes starting from the top down. If you're trying to add a custom route to an existing resource, the easier way is to do this. `collection` is if you want to use it on the group, `member` is if you want to add a custom route to an individual resource.

```
resources :coupons do
  collection do
    get 'redeem_coupon'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the additional suggestion to use collection and member!

Answer (score 2):

By listing your custom route first, you are overriding the other route. When rails gets a request, it simply starts from the top of your `routes.rb` file and goes with whichever route matches first.